# Getting an error while executing Material Ui

Tags: reactjs

I am importing materialui/core/Avatar in my React but getting an error as follows:-

**./src/@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette.js
Line 196:511:  '_formatMuiErrorMessage' is not defined  no-undef**

what can i do please suggest

Comment: This question is unclear and lacks proper explaination you  should provide more information for the same with the required code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that you installed material-ui/core ?

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Avatar from "@material-ui/core/Avatar";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  },
  remy: {
    background: "red",
    color: "blue"
  },
  travis: {
    background: "black"
  },
  cindy: {
    background: "green",
    color: "orangered"
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Avatar
        alt="Remy Sharp"
        src="/static/images/avatar/1.jpg"
        className={classes.remy}
      />
      <Avatar
        alt="Travis Howard"
        src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg"
        className={classes.travis}
      />
      <Avatar
        alt="Cindy Baker"
        src="/static/images/avatar/3.jpg"
        className={classes.cindy}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Follow this codesendbox example:

[Codesendbox exmpale](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-resonance-4n9y8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I don't think this is not useful, I provide him full detailed answer just in codesandbox, I don't understand what is the problem with that.
I added the code also to here.

Comment: Yeah this is very Useful. I could able to find out my error.-I am importing Material ui with wrong Syntax.Thanks